# JasperReport. Number of rows needed by a text

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

When I use a static band (columnFooter) I need to calculate the number of rows necessary to fit a text during the runtime.

```
int rows = numberOfRows_Calculator((String) ContentText, (java.awt.Font) font, (Integer, in   pixels) columnWidth);

TextFieldBuilder<String> textFieldBuilderMyStaticBand = new ComponentBuilders().text(ContentText);
textFieldBuilderDisclaimer.setFixedRows(rows);

jasperReportBuilder.columnFooter(textFieldBuilderMyStaticBand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is my solution, I Know that is not prefect because I can find problems with strings which contain words larger than column width...

```
private int numberOfRows_Calculator(String text, String fontName, int fontSize, int fontStyle, int columnWidth) {

    FontRenderContext context = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB).createGraphics().getFontRenderContext();
    java.awt.Font font = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
    double width;
    int numberOfRows = 0;

    int breakLineIndex;
    boolean continuee = true;
    String subtext = text;
    String breaklineString = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    int breaklineLength = breaklineString.length();

    do {
        breakLineIndex = subtext.indexOf(breaklineString);
        if (breakLineIndex > -1) {
            width = font.getStringBounds(subtext.substring(0, breakLineIndex), context).getWidth();
            numberOfRows = numberOfRows + (int) (width / columnWidth) + 1;
            subtext = subtext.substring(breakLineIndex + breaklineLength, subtext.length());
        } else {
            width = font.getStringBounds(subtext, context).getWidth();
            numberOfRows = numberOfRows + (int) (width / columnWidth) + 1;
            continuee = false;
        }
    } while (continuee);

    return numberOfRows;
}
```